# Windows 2012 server, created task not running

Tags: windows-server-2012, scripting, task-scheduler

Created a task o windows 2012 Server, to run a *.bat file. Set up to run at startup and repeat task every 15 minutes.

```
@ECHO OFF


REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

REM                             ENVIOS

REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZConnect\Export\Sonae\INVOICFF\*.* (MOVE C:\Indra\AZConnect\Export\Sonae\INVOICFF\*.* C:\Indra\AZConnect\5600000000427INT\INVOICFF\)
IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZConnect\Export\ECI\INVOICFF\*.* (MOVE C:\Indra\AZConnect\Export\ECI\INVOICFF\*.* C:\Indra\AZConnect\8422416999990INT\INVOICFF\)
IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZConnect\Export\Auchan\INVOICFF\*.* (MOVE C:\Indra\AZConnect\Export\Auchan\INVOICFF\*.* C:\Indra\AZConnect\5600000004289INT\INVOICFF\)


REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

REM                             RECEÇÃO

REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZConnect\5600000004289INT\ORDERSFF\*.* (MOVE C:\Indra\AZConnect\5600000004289INT\ORDERSFF\*.* C:\Indra\AZConnect\Import\ORDERSFF\)
IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZConnect\5600000000427INT\ORDERSFF\*.* (MOVE C:\Indra\AZConnect\5600000000427INT\ORDERSFF\*.* C:\Indra\AZConnect\Import\ORDERSFF\)
IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZConnect\8422416999990INT\ORDERSFF\*.* (MOVE C:\Indra\AZConnect\8422416999990INT\ORDERSFF\*.* C:\Indra\AZConnect\Import\ORDERSFF\)


REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM                     VALIDAÇÃO AZCONNECT EM MEMÓRIA
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

TASKKILL /F /IM AZCONNECT.EXE

REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM                         RELATÓRIOS
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\PBLIST.TXT (Type C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\PBLIST.TXT >> C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\Reports\PBLIST.txt)
IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\MBLIST.TXT (Type C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\MBLIST.TXT >> C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\Reports\MBLIST.TXT)
IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\ICONTROL*.TXT (MOVE C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\ICONTROL*.TXT C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\Reports\)

IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\PBLIST.TXT (del C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\PBLIST.TXT)
IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\MBLIST.TXT (del C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\MBLIST.TXT)

REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM                          COMUNICAÇÕES EDI
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

REM RASDIAL INDRA <user> <pass>

START /W C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\AZCONNECT.EXE /ER

REM RASDIAL INDRA /disconnect


REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM                         RELATÓRIOS
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\PBLIST.TXT (Type C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\PBLIST.TXT >> C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\Reports\PBLIST.txt)
IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\MBLIST.TXT (Type C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\MBLIST.TXT >> C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\Reports\MBLIST.TXT)
IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\ICONTROL*.TXT (MOVE C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\ICONTROL*.TXT C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\Reports\)

IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\PBLIST.TXT (del C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\PBLIST.TXT)
IF EXIST C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\MBLIST.TXT (del C:\Indra\AZCONNECT\MBLIST.TXT)
```

it worked for a couple of weeks, than for no reason at all (or one i can find) it stopped working. any thoughts on why?

the OS is: windows 2012 server r2 foundation

Answer (score 1):

Task is not running or script is not running? If the task is not running then script you have posted is of little importance. If the task is not running then I would start by looking at Operational Event LOG for Task Scheduler:

Event Viewer \ Applications and Services Logs \ Microsoft \ Windows \ TaskScheduler \ Operational

If there are no logs there, right click on the "Operational" and select "Enable Log". Restart and read what is going on.

Comment: let's see. if i run the script manually it runs with no problem whatsoever. other tasks i have created, such as backups, also run without any problems. that's why i'm not getting what's going on with this one. gonna check the log to rey to get some more info

Comment: the message i get on event viewer is the following:

Task Scheduler launched "{614ea871-57ca-4c72-abff-73ac084aa577}"  instance of task "\CHECK EDI"  due to system startup.

i don't see an error here, but it does not run, any thoughts?

Comment: Do you see EventID 200 (Action started) for that same task. You should see for the same task more EventID's. First 118 (task triggered by computer startup), then 100 (Task started) then 200 (Action started) then 129 (Process created) then 201 (Action completed) and finally 102 (Task completed). Are there any EventID's associated with this task immediately after 118 or 100 that is not 200?

Comment: Eg. if there is EventID telling you this Task is being registered, that could mean you are creating the task through GPO preferences in replace/update mode with delay option configured (which I did) and that the task is being rewritten before it has time to execute the action. So, do you see EventID's 200 and 201 for that task. If yes, then I would look closely into that script. Some actions need Admin rights. Under what account is script executing ("NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" with "Run with highest privileges" option selected or ???). So on and so forth ...

Comment: i get these message on event viewer:

Task Scheduler successfully finished "{ed4ca585-7f9b-4e89-9fbb-0ee0f047125e}" instance of the "\CHECK EDI" task for user "SERVIDOR\Administrator".

Event ID 102

the logical conclusion is that the task is being executed, right?

Comment: Task yes, Task is being executed. The problem is the efing Task is not what interests you ... you are interested is the action being executed (EventID's 200 and 201) because that is the whole point of the task. So, do you see those two EventID's. If not, I would concentrate on how is exactly task configured (post screenshots of the EVERY ASPECT of the task .... every aspect, very important because Devil is in the details). If yes, then I would concentrate on the rigths under which the task is run and on the script itself (eg. does the script executes OK if I run it through Startup GPO).

Comment: is it possible that the scrip works when i execute it manually (with no special privilleges) and not to run in a task?

Comment: Yes. I'm not checking your script yet because you didn't confirm do you see EventID's 200 and 201. Remember, when you execute the script you are executing it under your users context. When you are executing it during startup, it's probably configured to execute under System account. Not to say that you haven't mentioned the whole way, is some part of the script that is not running or all of the script. If only the part is not executing, which part? Come on man, more info, more, more info. Not to mention you are not answering on my old questions. Do you see EventID 200 and 201 ??? Yes or No ?

Comment: sorry toofat! i'm kind of playing a one mand band, i confess I didn't pay much attention to your questions. i indeed have eventid 200 (action started) and eventid 201 (action completed). but it does not run! if i go to task manager and click on "RUN" task it doesn't run. if i double click the bat file it executes it normally. the script is the one i posted on the original question, you can check it there

Comment: Wait, what? When you are logged on and execute the task manually it doesn't run? Did you try just changing the user under which context the task is executed, like your account for instance? Please do that and execute the task. If it runs, its rights issue. If it still doesn't run then screen capture all the task (every single little configuration of that task) and post it here. Also, does any other task on this server executes OK or ... ?

Comment: no, when i'm logged, if i execute the task manually (directly on the bat file) it runs as expected. when, in the task manager, i click "RUN", it does not run and nothing happens whatsoever.

Comment: Please work with me here. Did you try and change the user under which context the task is running? What happens when you do that? Does other tasks on that server work OK? This conversation could go on for months and months if we don't pick up the pace.

Comment: ok. i have other tasks, that also run a script, that run normally. this one has exactly the same conditions. i run both of them with "highest privileges"

Comment: OK. When logged on BAT runs OK but not through the Task although you have EventID's 200 and 201 (action is being executed). The only thing that comes to my mind is there is an issue with the "user under which context the task is running". I'm guessing "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM". What happens if you change this to your account and run the Task manually (while logged on)?

Comment: manually it runs as expected

Comment: Yes I know but what happens if you change the user under which context the task is running ("use the following user account" option in TaskScheduler)? Change it to your account and try to run task manually.

Comment: i have a warning concerning "an idle cpu condition has not been defined", could this be the reason?